# Smoothing caps/other methods to increase lifetime of incandescent segment displays (Looking for advice)

Tags: electrical-engineering

A while ago I salvaged a few incandescent seven segment from an old avionics module. [This](http://www.decadecounter.com/vta/articleview.php?item=1124) is the closest thing I could find online (I don't think its this exact model but same brand, pin number and such).

I plan to make a clock using an atmega328 using these as the display. They run off 5v DC so I was planning on driving them directly off the pins. Because of pin limitations I was going to multiplex them using the method described [here](https://electronics-project-hub.com/interfacing-7-segment-display-with-arduino/#:%7E:text=Multiplexing%20of%207%20segment%20display%20involve%20connecting%20each%20segments%20together,wires%20instead%20of%2032%20wires.).

Because I don't have many of these and online they go for about $70, preserving them and extending the lifetime would be ideal. I read online that keeping them on will extend the lifetime, and am wondering if switching them on and off would be damaging in anyway and if so would it be beneficial to use some caps to smooth out the power?

Comment: Running them at a lower voltage will certainly extend the lifetime. If you're talking about fast fluctuations in the voltage due to your driving method, I don't think that will effect the lifetime at all. It's too fast for the element to change temperature appreciably, and that's what matters. Thermal cycling due to for example blinking a digit *might* reduce its life.

Comment: I've done a bit more research, and it seems like limiting the inrush current would help extend the life. You could do that using constant current drivers, or using PWM to slowly ramp up the current when you turn a segment on.

Comment: You should include a picture of the seven segment displays.